# How can Python connect to IMS database?

Tags: python, jdbc, ims-db

Need to perform data reconciliation between DB2 and IMS.

Need help on connecting Python to IMS database.

Can JDBC connection help?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the [IMS JDBC](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPH2_15.1.0/com.ibm.ims15.doc.apg/ims_odbjdbcintro.htm) driver should work with the Python [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/). The code would look similar to the following:

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.ibm.ims.jdbc.IMSDriver', ['jdbc:ims://<host>:<port>/<psb_name>', '<user>', '<password>'],'</to/path/imsudb.jar>',)
```

You will probably need an IMS System Programmer to set up the necessary backend address spaces along with the IMS catalog:

1. IMS Connect (The IMS TCP/IP Gateway)
2. IMS Open Database Manager
3. IMS SCI/OM